# iOS Crash: Tapping the globe in keyboard to go to the emoji keyboard causes crash

Tags: ios, swift, crash, keyboard, emoji

## The Issue

The keyboard is shown when a uitextfield is tapped. Once the keyboard shows up, it works fine. I can change the keyboard to basically any keyboard except the emoji keyboard. Every time it tries to switch to the emoji keyboard, it crashes.

### This is the crash log

```
2019-02-13 17:19:01.775380-0500 xxxxxxxx[56054:2366411] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:1645: Could not retrieve region info
2019-02-13 17:19:01.775648-0500 xxxxxxx56054:2366411] -[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb424b425bd6497ae
2019-02-13 17:19:01.788405-0500 xxxxxxxx[56054:2366411] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb424b425bd6497ae'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001126831bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111c21735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001126a1f44 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112687ed6 ___forwarding___ + 1446
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112689da8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001125b6d38 CFLocaleCopyDisplayNameForPropertyValue + 1000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use something like `UserDefaults.standard.set("en_US", forKey: "AppleLanguages")`, make sure to set an array and not just a string. You should have `UserDefaults.standard.set(["en_US"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")` instead.

If you set a string, it can do weird things with the NSLocale object, effectively causing crashes on anything relying on it. The Emoji keyboard is one of these things, since all character has a localized alternative name, grabbed at runtime using the Locale of the user's device.

On a side note, it is not recommended to play with the languages settings, use the localization tools instead unless you think your use case is very specific.

Answer (score 0):

[image]check if "Use Base Internationalization" setting is turned off, turned it on and clean the project and run.

Comment: "Use Base Internationalization" is turned on and I cleaned the project multiple times. Still did not fix the issue.